# Promise Undefined instead of boolean

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, cheerio

I'm using Promise library to get result of another promise-request library with cheerio request but instead of boolean I keep getting `undefined`

```
return Promise.try(function () {
        .....
    }).then(function () {
        return self.checkGroupJoined(id);
    }).then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
```

and my method with `promise-request`

```
this.checkGroupJoined = function (steam_id) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'url',
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    return rp(options).then(function ($) {
        $('.maincontent').filter(function () {
            if ($(this).find('a.linkTitle[href="url"]').length > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return error.throw('Failed to parse body from response');
    });
};
```

Should I `promisifyAll` libraries?

Comment: you... aren't returning anything from `rp(options).then(function ($) {`. You just select some elements, filter them to a subset, then... throw it away.

Comment: so how to return? coz im returning after identifying if it is found or not.

Comment: what did you want to return? because right now you're just fitlering a collection of elements... there's nothing to return?

Comment: you dont need to downvote me for asking  question about the programming on the place where people keep asking questions about programming when they feel stuck :) greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this section

```
return rp(options).then(function ($) {
        // You are not returning anything here
        $('.maincontent').filter(function () {
            if ($(this).find('a.linkTitle[href="url"]').length > 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return error.throw('Failed to parse body from response');
    });
```

If you change your code to this it should work.

```
return rp(options).then(function ($) {
        let found = false;
        $('.maincontent').filter(function () {
            if ($(this).find('a.linkTitle[href="url"]').length > 0){
                found = true;
            }
        });
        return found;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return error.throw('Failed to parse body from response');
    });
```

Comment: yeah thats the thing I've missed, high five!

Comment: Why so complicated? And why would you use `filter` for looping (instead of `each`)?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you actually want is

```
….then(function ($) {
    return $('.maincontent').find('a.linkTitle[href="url"]').length > 0;
}).…
```

That will `return` the boolean from the promise callback so that it becomes the fulfillment value.